# Keras giving error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'" even though tensorflow-gpu is installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have tensorflow-gpu and keras installed in Python 3.6.8. But when I tried importing keras, it is giving the the error of Module not found. Also the error statements show the error is at a line inside keras at `import tensorflow as tf`. How to make keras import tensorflow-gpu instead of tensorflow? Do I have to go to the library code and change it? Or what else is the solution?

Comment: What tensorflow version do you use? Tf 1.12 comes together with Keras

Comment: @gameon67 I am using tensorflow-gpu 1.12. But it didn't came with keras. when i installed keras, it just installed h5py with it. I had to install tf and keras separately.

Comment: That's weird, did you follow the official tutorial to install tensorflow? If you can't import tensorflow at the first place it means you can't import Keras as well.

Comment: @gameon67 I don't have normal tensor flow, just the GPU one, but keras's code for tensor flow backend has `import tensorflow as tf`

Comment: It doesn't matter. When you install tensorflow you can choose between GPU or not. If you install the GPU version, Keras will automatically installed as well. `import tensorflow as tf` is valid for GPU or non-GPU. I suggest you reinstall tensorflow following the official site

Comment: @gameon67 I reinstalled both tf and keras, now it is working somehow. and tf does not install keras with it.

Comment: after `import tensorflow as tf` run this `from tensorflow import keras` . Is it working?

Comment: have you activate tensorflow source ? if not try on terminal- `source activate tensorflow`

Comment: @gameon67 I reinstalled both. Now it is working somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled both tf and keras and now everything is working fine. Don't know what had went wrong. Maybe the installation was not proper first time.